# How to pass dynamic dictionary name as arguments to model function

Tags: python

Finally created a stack overflow account since I couldn't find or phrase my question well. I'm learning python as I go and I'm stuck with defining a model variable that uses a function with dynamic dictionaries as its arguments. Pardon if I use incorrect terms as I'm new.

I have a models.py and a dict_config.py file

dict_config.py (contains two dictionaries)

```
DICT_1 = {
'name': 'sam',
'table': 'cust',
}

DICT_2 = {
'name': 'joe',
'table': 'cust',
}
```

models.py, I want to pass either dict_1 or dict_2 in my NameModel declaration

```
from dict_config import DICT_1, DICT_2

def dynamic_table(name, table):
... #some code

NameModel = dynamic_table(
DICT_1['name'],DICT_1['table'])

# or ...

NameModel = dynamic_table(
DICT_2['name'],DICT_2['table'])
```

I have an app.py file that uses NameModel and changes the config to either DICT_1 or DICT_2 depending if the string is found on the request.path

app.py code snippet

```
...
    model = NameModel

    if 'dict_1' in request.path:
        config = DICT_1
    elif 'dict_2' in request.path:
        config = DICT_2
...
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables. Nest them in another dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar I created a third dictionary and it worked. thanks